# Woocommerc rename field name in admin Order details

Tags: woocommerce

How to rename of label "Phone" in admin order details and in quick view without plugin?

**1) In Admin order:**

[image]

**2) Quick view order:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions that i can thinkof.

First solution is to generate your own po/mo files and set phone to be w/e you want. This solution will require almost 0 maintance.

Second solution would be with coding. This also is almost 0 maintance since we will only copy/past if there are any changes. For the overwriting part if someone else have better solution lets share.

```
//With following filter we can override billing phone label
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields' , 'order_admin_custom_fields',99,1 );
function order_admin_custom_fields( $fields ) { 
    $fields['phone'] = array(
        'label'=> __('Mobile phone','text-domain')
    );
    return $fields; 
}
// For quick view order is a bit more complicated since we dont have filter to use. 
//So we are removing the entire template and load a new one which is copy/paste from the original. 
//Location of the file is woocommerce/includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-orders.php
//The only difference is changing the phone text to whatever we want.
remove_action('admin_footer','order_preview_template');
add_action('admin_footer','order_preview_template_new');

function order_preview_template_new() {
?>
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-wc-modal-view-order">
            <div class="wc-backbone-modal wc-order-preview">
                <div class="wc-backbone-modal-content">
                    <section class="wc-backbone-modal-main" role="main">
                        <header class="wc-backbone-modal-header">
                            <mark class="order-status status-{{ data.status }}"><span>{{ data.status_name }}</span></mark>
                            <?php /* translators: %s: order ID */ ?>
                            <h1><?php echo esc_html( sprintf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce' ), '{{ data.order_number }}' ) ); ?></h1>
                            <button class="modal-close modal-close-link dashicons dashicons-no-alt">
                                <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Close modal panel', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                            </button>
                        </header>
                        <article>
                            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_start' ); ?>

                            <div class="wc-order-preview-addresses">
                                <div class="wc-order-preview-address">
                                    <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
                                    {{{ data.formatted_billing_address }}}

                                    <# if ( data.data.billing.email ) { #>
                                        <strong><?php esc_html_e( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ); ?></strong>
                                        <a href="mailto:{{ data.data.billing.email }}">{{ data.data.billing.email }}</a>
                                    <# } #>

                                    <# if ( data.data.billing.phone ) { #>
                                        <strong><?php esc_html_e( 'Mobile phone', 'text-domain' ); ?></strong>
                                        <a href="tel:{{ data.data.billing.phone }}">{{ data.data.billing.phone }}</a>
                                    <# } #>

                                    <# if ( data.payment_via ) { #>
                                        <strong><?php esc_html_e( 'Payment via', 'woocommerce' ); ?></strong>
                                        {{{ data.payment_via }}}
                                    <# } #>
                                </div>
                                <# if ( data.needs_shipping ) { #>
                                    <div class="wc-order-preview-address">
                                        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Shipping details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
                                        <# if ( data.ship_to_billing ) { #>
                                            {{{ data.formatted_billing_address }}}
                                        <# } else { #>
                                            <a href="{{ data.shipping_address_map_url }}" target="_blank">{{{ data.formatted_shipping_address }}}</a>
                                        <# } #>

                                        <# if ( data.shipping_via ) { #>
                                            <strong><?php esc_html_e( 'Shipping method', 'woocommerce' ); ?></strong>
                                            {{ data.shipping_via }}
                                        <# } #>
                                    </div>
                                <# } #>

                                <# if ( data.data.customer_note ) { #>
                                    <div class="wc-order-preview-note">
                                        <strong><?php esc_html_e( 'Note', 'woocommerce' ); ?></strong>
                                        {{ data.data.customer_note }}
                                    </div>
                                <# } #>
                            </div>

                            {{{ data.item_html }}}

                            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_end' ); ?>
                        </article>
                        <footer>
                            <div class="inner">
                                {{{ data.actions_html }}}

                                <a class="button button-primary button-large" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Edit this order', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'post.php?action=edit' ) ); ?>&post={{ data.data.id }}"><?php esc_html_e( 'Edit', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                            </div>
                        </footer>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wc-backbone-modal-backdrop modal-close"></div>
        </script>
<?php 
}
```